# a question on time, distance and speed and logic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a race of length d meters, A beats B by x meters and C by y meters. By what distance does B beat C in the same race?

A. (y-x)d/d-y meters

B. (y-x)d/d-x meters

C. d(d-y)/d-x meters

D. (y-x) meters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I believe the previous posters are not correct because they assume that each of the racers is moving at the same speed. I will assume that each of the racers is instead moving at his own *constant* speed.

Let *a*, *b*, and *c* be the speeds of the racers. Then we have these equations using $d = rt$:

$$
at = d
\\ bt = d - x
\\ ct = d - y
$$

If you think about it, the distance between racers B and C once B has finished the race is the difference between the total race distance and the distance C traveled in the time it took B to finish the race:

$$d - c\left(\frac{d}{b}\right)$$

Now, we have to make it look like one of the answer choices. First, subtract the two fractions. Then solve equations 2 and 3 for *b* and *c*, respectively, because none of the answer choices involve speeds. Substitute them into the fraction:

$$\frac{(d - x)d - (d - y)d}{bt}$$

Finally, substitute equation 2 in for *bt*, simplify a bit and you have one of the answer choices.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Just draw a straight line and put A, B and C locations (B being at $x$ behind A and C being at $y$ behind A).

I am sure that you can take from here.